# Why I still can read the resource even though it protected by `Rule` of using firestore database

Tags: firebase, spring-boot, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-firestore

Here is my database collections(users, resources) and documents(resource,uid)

[image]
[image]
In my `authenticaiton` I have 2 uid

- other_ud
- `QmYOQFXavvP0IQYv1nZ6XaedxJn1`

  `+users
        +QmYOQFXavvP0IQYv1nZ6XaedxJn1 <-- copied from above authentication uid 
          -isAdmin: true
  +resources
     +resource
          -first: A 
          -last: B
          -born: 2000`

I am using spring-boot , and here is my controller's method:

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/readone")
@ResponseBody
public  ResponseEntity<Object> readOneDocInOneCollection() throws JsonParseException, IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
    Firestore db = FirestoreClient.getFirestore();
    DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("resources").document("resource");
    // asynchronously retrieve the document
    ApiFuture<DocumentSnapshot> future = docRef.get();
    // block on response
    DocumentSnapshot document = future.get();
    User user = null;
    user = document.toObject(User.class);
    String serialized = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(user);
    return new ResponseEntity<Object>(serialized, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

### TO TEST

[image]
I use postman on chrome , I hit `http://localhost:8080/auth/user/readone`
attached with `id_token` pass through header `X-Firebase-Auth={my_token}` 
I still get the the result :

```
{"id":"1","first":"A","last":"B","born":2000,"middle":null}
```

Here is my `Rule`  for `Firestore`

```
service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
      match /resources/{resource} {

        function isAdmin() {
            return get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).isAdmin ||
            get(/databases/$(database)/documents/users/$(request.auth.uid)).data.isAdmin;
        }

        allow read: if isAdmin();
        allow create, update, delete: if isAdmin();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Maybe your question is missing information, but it sounds like you are make the request as a user who has isAdmin set to true, so your Rule would allow you to see the result. If you passed no token, does it still give you the data?

Comment: Even I log as isAdmin or not but I still get the results, it is wrong . should only admin who can see .